# JavaFX How can I set the location/coordinates of a pane?

Tags: java, javafx, location

How can I manually set the coordinates of a pane? When I click an ImageView I want to have a different ImageView popup at the same location, and then scale it up. I can get it to pop up but it only does so in the default top left corner of the parent pane for all the ImageViews.

Answer (score 1):

The short version: use [setLayoutX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) (and Y) or [setTranslateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-) (and Y).

The long version:

It depends on what your parent container is. You should make yourself familiar with [Working With Layouts in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm) and the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class.